# How to parse information from a log message in splunk

Tags: splunk

I have a log message in splunk as follows:
`Mismatched issue counts: 5 vs 9`

Is there a way to parse the 5 and 9 into variables and draw a graph using them?

I looked into [Splunk Custom Log format Parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31341915/splunk-custom-log-format-parsing)
and saw there is an option to use json to parse json log message. But how can I log as json and use spath in splunk chart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to log in JSON to parse custom logs.  Use regex.

````
```Extract the two numbers as fields 'a' and 'b'```
... | rex "Mismatched issue counts: (?<a>\d+) vs (?<b>\d+)"
```Group events by hour```
| bin span=1h _time
```Chart the results```
| chart max(a) as a, max(b) as b by _time
````